# How do I convert a STRING to a Real?

Tags: qgis, convert, attribute-joins, string

So I am trying to join some data I have (just numbers) to a map on QGIS.

However it when I try to join the data to map it shows up as a string instead of a real.

It's a just a normal exel file. I converted it to a CSV file and was able to join it to my map, however as a CSV file it was still a STRING so I couldn't use graduated symbols.

Comment: What's the source table format of the table you're joining? Is it a csv?

Comment: It's a just a normal exel file. I converted it to a CSV file and was able to join it to my map, however as a CSV file it was still a STRING so I couldn't use graduated symbols.

Comment: As a csv, you could create a csvt file that specifies the column type in the csv, then maybe qgis will have better luck with the join.

Comment: @SaultDon for the csvt file, what column type would I use? The data I want to add is only two columns, first is labeled GEOID, and the second is Percent Income.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a csv, then you can create a csvt file to go with it.

For example, if your csv is called file.csv then create a new text file called file.csvt

The csvt file only needs a single line with something like:
`"String","Real","String","String","Integer",...`

Where each column is the type found in the original csv. They just need to be surrounded by double quotes and separated by a comma.

There's some additional info at http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html where it also mentions you can specify width and scale of the Integer or Real types like:

From the site,

> "Integer(5)","Real(10.7)","String(15)"

or starting with gdal 2.0 or greater

> "Integer(Boolean)","Integer(Int16)" and "Real(Float32)"

Comment: So I did that, and the map just basically became covered in red hashes

Comment: Not to sure, maybe at this point if it's possible - share the data you're working with. Would make troubleshooting a lot easier. Or update you're question with some details on what exactly you've tried, step by step and the result with maybe some screenshots.

Comment: .... it was in toggle mode :( but thanks that help

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing data from a CSV file by '**Add Vector Layer**' option then by default the interpreted column type is 'string'. Try adding the data using '**Add Delimited Text Layer**' and choose no geometry option. It would guess the datatype.

Refer this [link](https://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/) for details about this option.

You can also look the 8th step of this [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html) for help regarding your csvt file.

Comment: I've just been adding by dragging and dropping. The weird thing is the data set for just Brooklyn works fine to add, but the entire dataset (all 5 boughs) doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to add the data using the **Add Delimited text Layer** option? It usually works for me and recognizes the datatypes automatically.